# Virtualisation vs Partitioning

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've been using Linux Mint (MATE 21.2) via Oracle Virtualbox and I've actually taken to it more than my host system (Windows 11). I would switch to Mint as my host system since all my important files are either on the cloud or on flash devices. However I was also looking into hard drive partitions, and I think that would be a good option to keep Windows on one side and Mint on the other, however I don't want to risk damaging my hard drive. Should I continue using Linux Mint via virtualisation or should I create a hard drive partition?

Comment: The answer is "Yes".  The only one who knows what you want and what is best for you is yourself.  Would it be possible to rephrase the question in some way so that it is not _soliciting opinions_ (this type of question falls under the "off-topic" category and is usually closed)?

Comment: What I mean is which option would be better for the health of my hard drive. I will rephrase the question.